# Pointer to class member as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, member

Is it possible to have non-type template parameter which is actually a pointer to a class member? What I'm looking to do is something like the following:

```
struct Person {
  Dog dog;
};

template <?? ptr>
struct Strange {
  // ...
};

typedef Strange<&Person::dog> weird;
```

My work so far leads me to believe that nothing of the sort is possible, but I'm curious if anyone has can say otherwise.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

From the standard:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (optionally cv-qualiﬁed) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - reference to object or reference to function,
> - **pointer to member.**

So it is allowed, and seems to work on `g++` like this:

```
template <Dog Person::*ptr>
struct Strange { ... };
```

Comment: Thanks! I can further generalize this as `template <class A, class B, A B::*member>`, which is useful to me. I suppose I should have read that section of the standard a bit closer.

Comment: Is there any way that the first two arguments A and B could be left out?

Comment: @user1158559 See proposal N3601. via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148749/pointer-to-class-member-as-a-template-parameter

Comment: any way to pass in a class method?

Comment: @xaxxon There is no separate thing such as method in C++. type of pointer to function includes member functions.

Comment: As I understand , it's available in c++ since first template appearance.

Comment: And in C++20 (maybe earlier) you can now do `template <auto member_ptr>` too!