# C++ Templates - Passing Class member

Tags: c++, class, templates, member

Alright guys!

I'm having a small problem here, to make it simpler, this is more or less how it looks like:

window.h

```
template <ObjectType &x>
class foo { stuff }
```

game.h

```
class gameclass { ObjectType a; }
```

main.cpp

```
gameclass mygame;
foo<mygame.a> fooa;
```

Now the fooa fails as somehow it doesn't allow me to send mygame's member 'a' as a template argument.

Now how can I send a class member as a template parameter?

Thank You

Comment: It doesn't make sense to. The template argument is supposed to be a *type*, not an object. If you want the *type* of `a`, then just do `foo<ObjectType> fooa;`.

Comment: Your `foo` template expects a *type*. You are passing a value computed at run-time. How do you expect to use `x` in the part marked as "stuff"? It's not clear what you want to do

Comment: You forgot to read your C++ book.

Comment: Sorry, wrote it wrong, please check now! And you don't need to vote down, that's just being rude...

Comment: I think @LightnessRacesinOrbit would not change his mind after this last edit (quite understandably, I must say). You should really read a book which covers templates.

Comment: @MiguelP: Downvotes are not a way to be rude (or at least, they should not be used as such). If you will hover the mouse on the downvote button, you should see a tooltip appearing that lists 3 possible motivations for downvoting: no research effort (any book on templates tells you what you are trying to do is non-sense), unclear (and your question really is, since the "stuff" part is not shown at all), or not useful (and I personally do not find this useful). So for me, all three criteria for downvoting are met. I downvoted, but I did not do so for being rude.

Comment: Still, you cannot pass a *pointer-to-member* as you've written. See my answer. I also agree with Andy Prowl, although I didn't downvoted you.

Comment: @sftrabbit you are wrong: a template argument does not need to be a `type`. It can be an integer or a member-function pointer. The latter is what is wanted here, I think.

Comment: @Walter You are right, but sftrabbit wrote his comment with the first revision of question, which was specifying `<class x>` ;)

Comment: @Synxis how can I know that ... sorry sftrabbit.

Comment: @Walter Haha, it's okay. I think comments (and answers) that were posted to old revisions should have a little revision reference next to them that you can click to see the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to pass a *non-type template parameter*, and more specifically, a *pointer-to-member*. For what you want, you have to user:

```
template<ObjectType gameclass::* ptr>
struct foo
// ...
```

Note that will allow you to access the member of an object only if you have a pointer to that object.

You can have more details [here (pointer-to-member as template parameter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880832/pointer-to-class-member-as-template-parameter) or [here (pointer-to-members)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member).

Note that you cannot pass the value of `mygame.a` to a template in the code you posted, because:

1. template parameters are compile-time, your value is runtime.
2. non-type template parameters cannot be any object type, only integral (or enum), pointer/reference to object/function, or pointer-to-member.

**EDIT**:
You have changed your template to `template<ObjectType& x>`. This is correct for [reference to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687540/non-type-template-parameters). However, `mygame.a` is not a reference, it is a value. To specify the member, you have to use the syntax `&mygame::a`, which forces you to use a pointer-to-member.