# c++ class member variable as a non type template argument, and how to use it?

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following use case,

```
struct Trans {
         double price;
};
struct Quote {
    double bid_price_1;
    double ask_price_1;
};
template<typename DataT, double DataT::*ptr>
class Return {
public:
    void operator()(DataT& data) {
        // print out the right field of the right class
        //std::cout << &DataT::ptr << std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    Quote quote {1, 2};
    Return<Quote, &Quote::bid_price_1> ret;
    ret(quote);
}
```

In the `operator` of `Return` class, I would like to be able to reference the right member variable of the right class, I have read the following post ([Pointer to class member as template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880832/pointer-to-class-member-as-template-parameter)), but it does not seem to mention how to retrieve the member variable part. I would like to know what is the right syntax to retrieve the member variable specified at compile time.

Comment: Are you looking for `(data.*ptr)`?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to address a member uses the operators `.*` (for a reference) and `->*` (for a pointer).  In your case

```
void operator()(DataT& data) {
    std::cout << data.*ptr << std::endl;
}
```